# How receives push notification in Windows with MAUI

Tags: c#, push-notification, maui

I'm creating an application using .NET 8 MAUI. The application registers the device in an `Azure Notification Hub`. From here, I can send push notifications to the different devices.

The problem I have with Windows is that the message arrives on the Windows application, only if the application is open. I like to understand if it is possible to register the application to wait for messages in the background.

I saw in the `Package.appxmanifest` for Windows those settings

[image]

but I can't find a way to use it. How do I have to configure the application in order to receive push notifications also when the application is closed?

Comment: You can check this document about [Quickstart: Sending a push notification (XAML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/quickstart-send-push-notification). Only the application is running or running in the background, it will receive the notification from the sever.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Interesting, thank you. So, do I have to create a background service for Windows in order to receive the push notification? Is there any documentation on how I can implement that? Thank you

Comment: You can check this [Quickstart: Creating and registering a raw notification background task (XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj709906(v=win.10)).